# Term that means to commit a sin when you know it is a sin?

Tags: sin, terminology

I am drawing a blank here, I know that such a term exists but I cannot remember it and my Google Fu is failing me.

There is a term for a sin that means that the sinner who committed the sin did it willfully and knowing that the action was indeed a sin.

It could fill in the blank here:

> Steve _____ (past tense verb) by lying, as he knew fully that lying was a sin.

> Forgive me, Lord, for my sins and _____ (noun).

Comment: It is called 'wilful sin' or 'deliberate sin' (in English). There are a number of words in the original Greek and that is a whole study all on its own. _Paraptoma_, _parabasis_, _hamartia_, _adikios_ and _anomia_.And they all mean different things.

Comment: @Nigel J There is a single-word for it, as long as I am remembering correctly... I will update my post if I remember it.

Comment: Sin of commission?

Comment: @David Anson  There are also sins of ommission. We may choose not to do something that we know is both the right thing to do, and which we ought to do. That is classified as sin the in the Bible in James 4:17.

Comment: Correct, but that is not the question being posed here :-)

Answer (score 2):

> If a person sins and commits a trespass against the LORD by lying to his neighbor about what was delivered to him for safekeeping, or about a pledge, or about a robbery, or if he has extorted from his neighbor, Leviticus‬ ‭6:2‬ ‭NKJV

I know it has been brought up already, but here’s a verse for “trespass” that seems clear that the sin was intentional.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the word you're looking for is **transgressed** & **transgressions**, which this gotquestions.org article ["What is the difference between iniquity, sin, and transgression?"](https://www.gotquestions.org/iniquity-sin-transgression.html) defines as:

> To transgress is to choose to intentionally disobey; transgression is willful trespassing.

But a more precise study of the 3 underlying Hebrew words commonly translated as iniquity, sin, and transgression highlights the differences *in other ways*, not in terms of intentionality.  Below are 3 very good infographics videos produced by [The Bible Project](https://bibleproject.com/explore/bad-word-series/):

- [Transgression](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cq-r9FFN5ew) (Hb: *Pesha*, Gr: *Paraptoma*]: violate the trust of others: betrayal of a relationship like in a treaty between nations as well as in the universal trust of one human to another who are all made in the image of God
- [Iniquity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w1zkwkI9oAw) (Hb: *Avon*): behaviors that are "bent" / "crooked" resulted from a conscience that is bent out of shape, such as the corruption of Israel leaders ignoring justice to the point that in Jerusalem crookedness was the new straight, so God punished them by letting Israel experienced the consequences of their crookedness
- [Sin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aNOZ7ocLD74) (Hb: *Khata*, Gr: *Hamartia*): failure to fulfill human nature's goal (to act in the image of God), thus failure to treat God and others with the honors they deserve, manifested through breaking the 10 commandments

A lesser candidate (but no verb form) is **culpability**, but it refers more to the *degree of responsibility*:

- Criminal law [distinguishes into 4 levels](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/suny-criminallaw/chapter/4-2-criminal-intent/) from most serious to least: purposely, knowingly, recklessly, and negligently.
- In Catholicism,  the most serious degree results in *mortal sin* when [the act fulfills 3 conditions](http://www.beginningcatholic.com/mortal-sin): 1) An act of grave matter that is 2) Committed with full knowledge and 3) Deliberate consent. (each term is very precisely defined within Catholic theology).  The same act is considered *venial sin* when factors such as addiction or passion lessen the force of deliberate consent.

Comment: Some may use "transgress" to mean wilful sin, but it's not universal. I certainly don't associate it with that meaning.

Comment: @curiousdannii I completely agree, other Google search results say as much.  I'm just trying to help Tyler to find the word, and to my surprise that's what gotquestions.org came up with.  I added entertaining + informative videos of word study on the underlying Hebrew words usually translated iniquity, sin, and transgression.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple I believe that "transgress"/"transgression" is indeed the word I was thinking of; however, it does seem that the literal definition of transgression does not include willfully/knowingly. It is possible that this is just how I was taught and that is why I am remembering it as such. I will be able to confirm this later in the week, at which point I will either post my own answer, or if it is indeed "transgression" that I was thinking of, I will accept your answer.

Comment: Psalm 19:12-13 distinguishes between hidden faults and presumptuous sins

Answer (score 0):

**Term that means to commit a sin when you know it is a sin?**

If you need a term in the past tense then the term **sinned** fits the bill for your given scenario:

> Steve ***sinned*** (past tense verb) by lying, as he knew fully that lying was a sin.
>
> Forgive me, Lord, for my sins and ***iniquity*** (noun).

[Sin](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/14004b.htm) is a moral evil and a morally bad act.

[Iniquity](https://iblp.org/questions/what-iniquity) is the inner act of willfulness against God.

The following article may contain some useful information:

- [What is the difference between iniquity, sin, and transgression?](https://www.gotquestions.org/iniquity-sin-transgression.html)

Answer (score -1):

The old Lord's Prayer (Matt 6: 12) goes  :

"... And forgive us our trespasses, as we forgive them that trespass

against us. ". So, the word `trespassed 'can be used to fill in the first sentence. As for the second sentence, the word` short-comings' should be a good option in that  it does not take willfulness as a pre-requisite.